# Extract info from a dict turned list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-science

I have a list that has been extracted from a dictionary and the first element of the new list looks like this:
[image]

The total # of elements in my list are 4200; I was wondering how would I extract the `'uri'` of each individual element and place it into a new list.

Comment: You need to provide you data/code as **text** not images.

Answer (score 1):

Quick way using list comprehension:

```
[elem['nft_metadata']['data']['uri'] for elem in result['minted_nfts']]
```